# Dynamically created Jenkins Slave using Jenkins Docker Plugin get removed in the middle of Job execution

Tags: api, docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

I am using Jenkins-Docker-Pluginhttps://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin to dynamically create containers and use them as Jenkins Slaves. This is working fine for some jobs. However for some longer running jobs (10mins >) docker container get removed in midway. Making job failed.

I have tried increasing various timeout options in plugin configuration, However no result. Can anyone please help.

Comment: could post log of jenkins job failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I am quite late to post answer here. I am able to get the root cause of the issue. Problem was using two Jenkins instance with same Jenkins Home Directory. Seems Jenkins Docker plugin runs daemon to kill docker container associated with Jenkins Master. As we are running two Jenkins instance with same Jenkins Home directory (Copy of It) Docker containers started for CI work get deleted due to daemon of each other.